# Solving a ODE with integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

$$(x^2 -1) \frac{dy}{dx}  +  2xy  =  x$$

First I divided both sides by $(x^2 - 1)$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} + {2x \over x^2 - 1}y = {x \over x^2 - 1}
$$

and then I found the integrating factor $x^2 - 1$ and multiples both sides with this and that leads me to the initial question... How do I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the integrating factor lead you right back to the original equation should show you that it's already in the form of the product rule. Observe that

$$ (x^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx} + 2xy = \frac{d}{dx}\big((x^2-1)y\big) $$

Therefore

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\big((x^2-1)y\big) = x $$

And you can integrate throughout to get

$$ (x^2-1)y = \frac{x^2}{2} + c $$

Does this make sense?

Comment: you integrate (x^2-1) to y. What happened to 2xy?

Comment: Do you understand the product rule? which part confused you?

Comment: Note that $2x$ is the derivative of $(x^2-1)$

Comment: d/dx ((x^2-1)y) = (yx^2) d/dx - (y) d/dx =/= (x^2-1)dy/dx + 2xy. I do not understand this part :/

Comment: The product rule states $$ (u(x)y(x))' = u(x)y'(x) + u'(x)y(x) $$ Now let $u(x) = x^2-1$

Answer (score 1):

Now you know that you can get some insight into the problem by computing
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl((x^2-1)y(x)\Bigr).
$$
The idea of an integrating factor $\mu$ is that you can go from $y'+py=q$ via $\frac{μ'}μ=p$ to
$$
(μy)'=μy'+μ'y=μq\implies y=\frac1μ\int μq\,dx.
$$
That is, the solution of the ODE is reduced to the computation of an "ordinary" integral.

Comment: I am not familiar with differential equations yet.  How did you get this expression and how do I solve with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This equation dosen't need an integrating factor. Its already a derivative
$$(x^2 -1) \frac{dy}{dx}  +  2xy  =  x$$
$$\mu (x)y'+\mu ' (x)y=x$$
where $\mu =x^2-1$
$$(\mu (x)y)'=x$$
Integrate both side to get the function y(x)